# Compare each element of a DataFrame column with every element of another column

Tags: python, dataframe

I have two DataFrames of unequal lengths, *Alerts* and *Labels*. They both have a column named ID. I want to create a new column in the DataFrame Labels with true if its ID matches any ID in Alerts and false the ID is not present in Alerts.

Comment: You should also show your attempts while asking questions. Welcome to Stack Overflow!! Do not forget to accept the answers if they help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `Labels` and `Alerts` as dataframe names:

```
Labels['new_col'] = Labels['ID'].apply(lambda x:True if x in Alerts['ID'] else False)
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked. I will show my attempts in future questions, thanks for the heads up.